# Allocate a multidimensional array without one dimension

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

If I got this correctly, `int[][10]` is a bidimensional array type without the first dimension. This should decay into a `int(*)[10]` pointer when used as a function argument type.

I have two questions:

- why is this failing in a local scope

  ```
  int a[][10];
  ```

with

> error: definition of variable with array type needs an explicit size or an initializer

- what is the dimension of the memory area pointed by p2

  ```
  auto p2 = std::make_unique<int[][10]>(2);
  ```

?

Comment: Is this for academic purposes or for real code? In real code, it's usually easier to allocate a one-dimensional array and calculate the offset every time you access an element.

Comment: Oh just for curiosity's sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> •what is the dimension of the memory area pointed by p2

The memory area pointed to by p2 is linear.:) 
But it represents a two-dimensional array of type `int[2][10]`

When you declare an array you have to specify its size that the compiler could be able to determine the size of the memory to allocate and to determine the type of the object at compile-time.

For this declaration if it is not a declaration of a function parameter that is implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element of the array

```
int a[][10];
```

the type of a is incompllete. The compiler does not know the exact type of a. So it issues an error.

The difference between this declaration

```
auto p2 = std::make_unique<int[][10]>(2);
```

and this one

```
int a[][10];
```

that in the first case the array is defined at run-time dynamically and in the second case the array is defined at compile-time and the compiler must know its type before running the program.

Comment: Excellent answer, I understood everything. Thanks!